# Typescript type that is method of a module

Tags: typescript

How do I declare a type that is a method of an imported module?

Suppose I have a simple file with functions:

```js
// MyModule.ts

export const Method1 = () => {}
export const Method2 = () => {}
export const Method3 = () => {}
```

Now suppose I wanted to make a cool function that took one of those functions above as a parameter and then called it.

```
// OtherModule.ts

import * as methods from './MyModule'

//pesudocode that doesn't work
const CoolFunction = (method: typeof methods) => {
    method()
}
```

I want the method I pass to CoolFunction to be type checked. How do I do that?

```
// LastModule.ts
import * as m from './MyModule'
import { CoolFunction } from './OtherModule'

// typescript should yell at me if I try to do this
const badFunction = () => void
CoolFunction(badFunction)

// but any of these should be allowed
CoolFunction(m.Method1)
CoolFunction(m.Method2)
CoolFunction(m.Method3)
```

Comment: So just one of those 3 functions and no others ?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir updated

Answer (score 3):

You could use branded type on methods.

```
// Should work with imports too
namespace methods {
    const methodKey = Symbol.for("methodKey");
    export const Method1 = Object.assign(() => {}, { __brand: methodKey });
    export const Method2 = Object.assign(() => {}, { __brand: methodKey });
    export const Method3 = Object.assign(() => {}, { __brand: methodKey });
}

const CoolFunction = (method: typeof methods[keyof typeof methods]) => {
    method()
}


const badFunction = () => { }
CoolFunction(badFunction) //error

CoolFunction(methods.Method1) // ok
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEGUAsHsFcBsAmoDu0BOBrVBLALpKDgLYAOGeAzqHtNAFAB2AhsQKaWnMDGbo7BaImoBveqAmhu0RpTz82gxAGk2AT1ABeCGuIAjaPAB0AMwwAKAEQCYK9ZYCUAbnGS2AD3Lp502fICyirYAjFqgAPJ6AFZs3HhGzJSUOADmjObmDloAfKAiAL4ANHmgAPqleujMjIgAXApKqhr5zq4SHl4+MnKggUoATGGRMXEJSanpmTl5RSXlldV1DbZNoC0ukqAdFFLdAUFCAMxD0bHxiclpGVmauQXFImUVVTX1NkKr6-T59PS+PQBhOjwABisEYcRwMjC5neSzwalIbGgJmWQkoAG1MOoUTREcjUXDKABdG53NpoxCZb6-P57UB6ZiIMEQvBQxgwsklH5AwwsyEycyM5nggWMLIgNjodAYX680GitmColGPohCVgaCYIA)

Comment: I like this, but wouldn't it be better to use a unique symbol which can't be retrieved and can't clash in the registry?